# Modified dependencies in python package do not show up

Tags: python, package, pip

In a Python package I have, in `setup.py` I modified the dependencies by removing the condition on the version number:

```
setup(
    name='MyTool',
    version='0.1.5',
    author='myname',
    author_email='myname@myname.com',
    packages=['mytool'],
    scripts=['bin/my_tool.py'],
    url='https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mytool',
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='This is my tool.',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    install_requires=[
        "scipy",
        "numpy",
        "prettytable"
    ],
)
```

I ran:

```
$ python setup.py sdist
$ python setup.py sdist upload
```

But when I run `pip`, it refers to the previous requirements:

```
$ sudo pip install  MyTool
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MyTool in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from MyTool)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from MyTool)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): prettytable>=0.7.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from MyTool)
Cleaning up...
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That means you have already installed package MyTool.
If you want to install the latest version (the uploaded version just now), try:

```
sudo pip install -U MyTool
```